# Need to connect multiple workbooks with the same set of data sources in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 workbooks named "a" and "b" both using the same data sources. In workbook "a", I have first made all live connections to extracts and then saved all 8 data sources on tableau server.
Now in workbook "b" , I have replaced all the live connections with the tableau data source connections.

My question here is : 
1. Is workbook "b" connecting to extracts on the server?

2. Will workbook "b" refresh data sources as well as calculated fields if I change the data sources on the server?
3. When I see workbook "b's" data soures(See image no 5 in file), I can see that it says Live instead of Extract. Why is it so ?

[image: Server Images]

Comment: What do you mean when you say "live connections to extracts" in the second sentence? That's a bit contradictory. Do you mean you have a live connection to an external data source and also created an associated extract? (that's a normal case) Or do you mean you connected directly to a TDE file losing the connection to the original source? (sometimes called a naked extract)

Comment: Hi Alex, I meant to say that the connection was earlier live and since we were facing performance issues with the live connection, we changed it to extract and then published the extracts on the server. Followed by this we connected workbook "b" to the same set of extracts on the server and not locally.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is workbook "b" connecting to extracts on the server? 
   **Yes**
2. Will workbook "b" refresh data sources as well as calculated fields if I change the data sources on the server? 
   **It would but you should ideally do it on desktop, test it and then publish to server.**
3. When I see workbook "b's" data soures(See image no 5 in file), I can see that it says Live instead of Extract. Why is it so ? 
   **Because you are connecting to the published data source which is live.**

**For more details go to: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_datasources_about.html**

Comment: For point 2, you should probably also refresh the extract before republishing. And also have the server refresh extracts on schedule usually.

Comment: You can also improve performance by filtering, hiding fields, aggregating and optimizing extracts - but realize that doing so comes with implications for analysis. Clearly if you filter out rows or hide fields, that data is not available from the extract. Also if you aggregate an extract, it can dramatically improve speed assuming you plan to simply display those pre-aggregated results. But can also lead to misleading results if you don't understand the impact of the aggregation -- i.e. performing additional sums of precomputed sums is fine, but count distincts of count distinct is not.